# Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?

Tags: flutter, yaml

I am trying to make my first app. I tried to work it out but i couldn't.Can anyone help me please?

-I tried other solutions but i am new to these indentation problems.
-I tried yaml validators but no solution.

```dart
dependencies: 
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
description: "A new Flutter application."
dev_dependencies: 
flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
   firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+3
  environment:
    sdk: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
name: masque
version: 1.0.0+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebase_auth` looks out of place. Also there are indentation issues. Can you try this below?

```
name: masque
version: 1.0.0+1
dependencies: 
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+3
description: "A new Flutter application."
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 12):

Spaces are important in YAML  file.
So Please remove space before -asset:
instead of this

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
   assets:
     - assets/images/
```

fix it like this way

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
     - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 3):

---

In my case I just should have to rename my "assets" folder to some another one.
There was this error when I had such code

---

assets:
   - assets/image.jpg

---

**I replaced to this:**

assets:
   - images/image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Make Sure You've no White Space Before **assets:**

Example:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - assets/body_builder.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name: masque
description: "A new Flutter application."

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies: 
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+3
  # You can put packages here

dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  # You can put assets here
```

More informations [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec).

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget to click on the "Pub get" written on the top side, I had the same problem. Clicking "Pub get" will solve all your problems. Good luck.